# Can $f'(c)$ exist if $f'(x)$ is not continuous at c

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

Can a derivative function have a jump discontinuity at a point and the function still be differentiable at that point? I'm pretty sure it cannot, since it means that the secant slopes do not tend to the same number, but I am not sure how to prove it from the definitions. I have read that the derivative function can have an essential discontinuity at a point and the function still be differentiable at that point. i.e.

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x^2sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & \quad x \ne 0 \\
            0 & \quad x = 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$.

Are there any other kinds of discontinuity or are these only the two cases. Many thanks.

Comment: The derivative need not be continuous, but it must satisfy the IVP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It follows from [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), that if $f$ is a differentiable function and if $f'$ is discontinuous at $a\in D_f$, then the only possible cause of that discontinuity is that the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f'(x)$ doesn't exist.

Comment: but can f'(a) still exist then? I know intuitively it can't but I am not too sure how to show it. Can the derivative function look like $$
f'(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            -1 & \quad x < 0 \\ 0 & \quad x=0\\
            1 & \quad x > 0
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Comment: No, by Darboux's theorem.